# Nonlinear Wald Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power, type-i-and-ii-errors, wald-test

Say we have a bivariate distribution

$~~~~~f(x,y|\theta=\{a,b,t,c\}).$

An event of interest is when ab=c, that is,

$~~~~~H_0: g(\theta)=c-ab=0$  versus  $H_1: g(\theta)=c-ab \neq 0.$

I attempt to carry out this test using the results from equation (9-21) of [this text](https://spu.fem.uniag.sk/cvicenia/ksov/obtulovic/Mana%C5%BE.%20%C5%A1tatistika%20a%20ekonometria/EconometricsGREENE.pdf).

First, I calculated the MLEs based on the negative log likelihood using nlm in R. Taking, the function of interest:

$~~~~~g(\theta)= c-ab$

a vector of the partial derivatives of the function of interest:

$~~~~~G(\theta)= [-b, -a, 0, 1]'$

observed fisher information matrix (no *(-1) necessary because minimization was done on the negative log likelihood so it is already negative):

$~~~~~V = H^{-1}~~~~~$

the Wald test statistic should be

$~~~~~W = g(\widehat{\theta})'~[G(\widehat{\theta})~V~G(\widehat{\theta})']^{-1}~g(\widehat{\theta})$.

I realize the text is in a regression context, but MLEs satisfying some regularity conditions are asymptotically normally distributed so I figured the same formula would hold but the results make me wonder... if something is wrong or the Wald test is just really bad here.

Basic code outline (MLE estimation has been rigorously tested as working):

```
MLEs.full<-nlm(f=loglike.full,p=c(astart,bstart,tstart,cstart),hessian = T,y=data)
estimate<-MLEs.full$estimate[4]-MLEs.full$estimate[1]*MLEs.full$estimate[2]
V<-ginv(MLEs.full$hessian)
CC<- t(as.matrix(c(-MLEs.full$estimate[2],-MLEs.full$estimate[1],0,1)))
as.numeric(estimate %*%ginv(CC %*% V %*% t(CC))%*% estimate)
```

Results when looped through:
[image]

Comment: How did you get the power?

Comment: I simulated data for a case where c-ab!= 0; e.g. c=1, a=3, b=4, t=3 and counted how many times I rejected in 5000 simulations.

Comment: What kind of bivariate distribution did you use (first formula)? It is uncommon that power of lrt is 0.10 when sample size = 100 and c-ab = -11.